# Where should .dll files be placed when using lua5.1?

Tags: dll, lua, appium, lua-5.1

I am using lua5.1 and I have a devicecomm.dll library that I need to use. However, I'm not sure where this library should be placed. On Mac I know that the location should be under /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1
Does anyone know the equivalent location to this, but for Windows? Also, would I need to update any of my environment variables when adding this library?

Answer (score 0):

DLL files should be placed in the same directory where the Lua interpreter is.

If the DLL file is not a Lua binary module (for example a DLL used with ffi in LuaJIT) you can place it where you want, but beware of DLL dependencies, which can turn in a true nightmare (as known as "DLL hell")

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also did some research and I saw that it should be placed in the same directory as the app .exe file, which is consistent with your answer. I tried that, however I'm still having issues running my program. I think my issue is perhaps something different now.